# Is it possible to find a legendary in a vending machine?

Tags: borderlands-2

i have seen a video where a person finds a legendary in a vending machine as the item for the day, is this possible? Or did he simply mod his game to make it look like he did so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible as you would find in this [link](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_The_Bee)

> The Bee has a chance to be the Item of the Day in Dr. Zed's Meds so check the machines often.

And so can other weapons, such as the Unkempt Harold which can be found in Torgue's vending machine as the item of the day. See [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9j1sZTci8w).

Comment: Actually the Torgue vending machine will *always* have a legendary, so it's a special case. But I've seen a legendary in Marcus' guns. That was once in 300 hours of play time though, so don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Regular vending machines always have a small chance to have a legendary in them, and the Torgue vending machines in the second campaign DLC are actually guaranteed to have a legendary item as their Item Of The Day, though as their name suggests, it will always be a Torgue-brand item, and also those machines don't take cash, only Torgue Tokens from the rest of the DLC.